# Proof of the Hairy Ball Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, de-rham-cohomology

In the proof of the Hairy Ball theorem, we use the diffeomorphisms,

$F_t(x)=\cos(\pi t)x+\sin(\pi t)v(x)$

where $v(x)$ is the non-vanishing vector field, then use the fact that

$F_1^*=F_0^*$ as pullbacks on the cohomology to reach a contradiction.

However, I cannot see why this same proof would not work for $S^1$ for example>

Isn't $F_t$ a diffeomorphism (Actually, I think we just need it to be a smooth map) regardless of whether $n$ is even or odd, where $S^n$ is the $n$-sphere?

For example, considering $S^1$, and the usual non-vanishing tangent vector, we have

$F_t(\theta)=(\cos(\pi t+\theta),\sin(\pi t+\theta))$

and this looks like a diffeomorphism, basically, just rotating the point $(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$ by the angle $\pi t$.

Where is the part where we use the evenness of the dimension?

The contradiction is reached in the following manner, without reference to the degree.

For any $\omega$, a $2m$-form on $S^{2m}$, we have that $F_0^*(\omega)=F_1^*(\omega)$ since $F:[0,1]\times S^{2m}\to S^{2m}$ is a smooth map, and thus, we would have that $[\omega]=-[\omega]$ since $F_0$ is the identity map and $F_1$ is the antipodal map, and since this holds for any $\omega$, we have that $H^{2m}(S^{2m})=0$. However, since $S^{2m}$ is a compact orientable manifold, then $H^{2m}(S^{2m})\neq 0$ (This is done by considering the non-vanishing volume form.)

I cannot see where the evenness is used here either.

Comment: I would suggest "in a proof" rather than "in the proof", or "in the proof I have been shown" - such key theorems often have more than one proof, from different directions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $F_0=id_{\Bbb S^n}$ and $F_1=-id_{\Bbb S^n}$. Then $F_0$ has degree 1 and $F_1$ has degree $(-1)^{n+1}$, so $F_0^*\neq F_1^*$ if $n$ is even.

**Edit:** In the case where $n$ is odd, $F_1^*([\omega])\neq -[\omega]$ but you have $F_1^*([\omega])=[\omega]$ so you won't reach a contradiction.

Comment: That's weird.
The course proved that if $F:M\times [0,1]\to N$ is a smooth map, then $F_1^*=F_0^*$ without even referring to the degree of the map (We actually still haven't reached that part.)
Could it be that $F:[0,1]\times S^n\to S^n$ is not a smooth map when $n$ is even?

Comment: No the map is smooth. $F_1$ and $F_0$ don't have the same degree if $n$ is even, so they can't induce the same map. You proved that if there is a non zero vector field on the sphere, then the induced maps are the same, this is you contradiction.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm ignorant on these matters, but let me show you how he proved that smooth maps induce the same pullback on the cohomology. I cannot figure the faulty step.

Starting with some $\alpha$ a $k$-form on $N$, $F^*\alpha=\beta+dt\wedge \gamma$ where $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are forms that depend on $t$.

Then, he writes the differentiation operator in terms of $d|_M$ where $d|_M$ is the exterior differentiation on $M$, ignoring $t$.

Then, $F_1^*\alpha-F_0^*\alpha=d|_M\int_0^1 \gamma dt$ and thus they differ by an exact form, and thus are the same on the cohomology.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to prove/understand ? The (classical) proof works like this: the induced maps are the same **if** you have a non zero vector field on the $n$-sphere. However, the induced maps can't be the same if $n$ is even because $F_0$ and $F_1$ don't have the same degree. Hence there is no non-zero vector field on the $n$-sphere if $n$-is even.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that he proved the induced maps are actually the same (in a previous lemma) without any reference to degrees. Perhaps that lemma is wrong since he only assumed the smoothness condition for them to induce the same pullback maps, and he did it for general manifolds. I guess there was a mistake there I just couldn't pick up.

Comment: No the lemma is correct and it doesn't use the notion of degree. But the contradiction comes from the degree.

Comment: I am sorry if this is sounding stupid, but then, why couldn't we use the same proof for $S^1$? I mean, we would have that $F_0^*(\omega)=\omega$ and $F_1^*(\omega)=-\omega$ meaning that $H^1(S^1)=0$ which yields a contradiction since $S^1$ is a compact orientable manifold. This was what drove me to ask this question (Rather than checking the degrees, which I am not acquainted with, he gets the contradiction by showing that $H^{2m}(S^{2m})=0$.

Comment: Ok what I need to understand is how do you reach to a contradiction if you don't use degree? Maybe you can write the proof in your post

Comment: Alright, I did that. Please take a look

Comment: I edited my answer